# How to configure "JWKS_URL" in .env file of Dispatch?

Tags: environment-variables, dispatch, netflix

I was checking the [.env example](https://github.com/Netflix/dispatch/blob/develop/docker/.env.example) that is mentioned in the [documentation](https://hawkins.gitbook.io/dispatch/installation), but I don't have a clue of what to put in `JWKS_URL=`.

What am I supposed to put there?